# Java 8 Lambda Sort With Variable Method Reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator

I have a statement:

```
searchResults.sort(Comparator.comparing(WCCTableRowData::getD));
```

where getD is an accessor in the class WCCTableRowData and searchResults is a list of WCCTableRowData. The WCCTableRowData class has accessors from getA through getZ. I need to be able to set the sort field on the fly from a passed in variable. Is there an elegant way to do this or will I need a series of if statements or similar?

**UPDATE 1**
Unfortunately, neither approach in the accepted answer worked though I think in general the direction is correct. With approach 2 I get:

[image: Intelli Sense]

With approach 1, row.getField does not pick up the getField method in WCCTableRowData class and I get similar "does not conform to upper bound(s)" error. I think the error is saying that WCCTableRowData class has to implement Comparable?

Comment: Just pass in a `Function<WCCTableRowData, Comparable<?>>`, call it `extractor`. Then you can simply do `searchResults.sort(Comparator.comparing(extractor))`.

Comment: Suggestion: it is always better to paste the stacktrace as code block instead of an screenshot

Comment: I have just found out that at least in Eclipse Neon with ECJ Java compiler, usage of `Comparable<?>` in solution #2 leads to severe type issues like the one you posted about. To prevent such issues, one may change type reference to just `Comparable` (raw type) in `getters` definition. You will get type warnings in variable definition, of course, but you may easily overcome those by prepending a @SuppressWarnings:
`@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Map<String, Function<WCCTableRowData, Comparable>> getters = ...`

Unchecked conversion warning in `comparing()` could be suppressed as well.

Comment: Please note that the same holds for solution #1: just change return type of `getField` to `Comparable` (`Comparable getField(final String name) {...}`) and you will have a working solution.

Comment: @rpax. I agree but in this case it was JDeveloper intellisense during design time and I could not copy out the text from the info bubble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to add a method in `WCCTableRowData` that can be given a field name and returns the value of that field.

```
class WCCTableRowData {
    Comparable<?> getField(String name) { ... }
}

String name = "C";
searchResults.sort(Comparator.comparing(row -> row.getField(name)));
```

If you don't want to modify the class, then you could set up an external map.

```
Map<String, Function<WCCTableRowData, Comparable<?>>> getters = new HashMap<>();
getters.put("A", WCCTableRowData::getA);
getters.put("B", WCCTableRowData::getB);
getters.put("C", WCCTableRowData::getC);

String name = "C";
searchResults.sort(Comparator.comparing(getters.get(name)));
```

Comment: Make sure to make `getters` a `static final` field, preferably wrapped in `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`.

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to store method references in a map with keys - values of your variable. It would be analogue of switch statement. You can use guava `ImmutableMap.<WCCTableRowData, Comparable<?>>of()` to make it a bit nicer.

**Update**

You can explicitly tell that comparator which is constructed by `Comparator.comparing(...)` is comparing `Comparable` :

```
Comparator.<WCCTableRowData, Comparable>comparing(getters.get(name));
```

Also you can just store comparators of your object (sounds much more reasonable but adds boilerplate), not functions returning comparables:

```
Map<String, Comparator<WCCTableRowData>> comparators = new HashMap<>();
comparators.put("A", Comparator.comparing(WCCTableRowData::getX));
comparators.put("B", Comparator.comparing(WCCTableRowData::getY));

String name = "C";
searchResults.sort(comparators.get(name));
```

Comment: Nice! To me, this approach is more general than the former, since key `"A"` becomes not just a field designator, but rather a way to describe a whole comparator strategy, made from linking different comparator in chains. For example, you could add this key:

`comparators.put("XY", Comparator.comparing(WCCTableRowData::getX).thenComparing(WCCTableRowData::getY);`

and have `"XY"` as a key to refer to this particular ordering, which is not doable in the previous approach.

For some (non-trivial) cases this may prove useful, thank you!